# Simple Google Sheets script now slow and unreliable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote the following script to add a menu item and several custom sort-and-color functions to one of my Google spreadsheets.  The spreadsheet is only about 40 rows and 10 columns.  The script used to run in a matter of moments, but now it takes about 25 seconds to run one of the three main functions.  Furthermore, when the script is complete, I do not see the results of the sort and row coloring until I refresh my browser.  Can anyone point me in the right direction of what's going on?

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Pastoral Care", functionName: "customSort1"},{name: "Read Aloud Prayers", functionName: "customSort2"},{name: "Priests' Notes", functionName: "customSort3"} ];
  ss.addMenu("Layout", menuEntries);
}

function customSort1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  sheet.sort(2, true).sort(3, true).sort(1, true);

  var endRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var endColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

  for (var r = 2; r <= endRow; r++) {
    colorRowPastoralCare(r, endColumn);
  }
}

function customSort2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  sheet.sort(2, true).sort(3, true).sort(5, false);

  var endRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var endColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

  for (var r = 2; r <= endRow; r++) {
    colorRowReadAloudPrayers(r, endColumn);
  }
}

function customSort3() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  sheet.sort(2, true).sort(3, true).sort(6, false);

  var endRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var endColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

  for (var r = 2; r <= endRow; r++) {
    colorRowPriestsNotes(r, endColumn);
  }
}

function colorRowPastoralCare(r, endColumn){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(r, 1, 1, endColumn);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var row = data[0];

  if(row[0] === ""){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 255);
  }else if(row[0] === "1 Acute"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 211, 216);
  }else if(row[0] === "2 Recovering"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 236, 218);
  }else if(row[0] === "3 Long-term"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 254, 220);
  }else if(row[0] === "4 Prayer only"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(213, 255, 227);
  }else if(row[0] === "5 Homebound"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(215, 238, 253);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
}

function colorRowReadAloudPrayers(r, endColumn){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(r, 1, 1, endColumn);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var row = data[0];

  if(row[4] === ""){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 255);
  }else if(row[4] === "Y"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(213, 255, 227);
  }else if(row[4] === "N"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(215, 238, 253);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
}

function colorRowPriestsNotes(r, endColumn){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(r, 1, 1, endColumn);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var row = data[0];

  if(row[5] === ""){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 255);
  }else if(row[5] === "Y"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(213, 255, 227);
  }else if(row[5] === "N"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(215, 238, 253);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug it?  Check view executions.  You can use Logger.log and view the results there also.

Comment: Which one of the function is slow? Sidenote: There is no need to include `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` as the last function statement on "main functions" (i.e. functions called from the custom menu)

Comment: Thank you @Cooper and @Rubén!  I went to View > Executions, but all of the entries report "No logs are available for this execution."  I did also remove the call to `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`. I'm pretty new to the Google environment, so I'm afraid I'm stumped.  But, again, I really appreciate you both taking the time to respond!

Comment: Well then I think you'll just have to single step through the program in debug mode and figure out what's happening.

Comment: This `sheet.sort(2, true).sort(3, true).sort(1, true);` is incorrect I get the error: `Exception: The parameters (number,(class)) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.sort. (ile "ag2")` I believe you're missing the sortSpecObj as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object))

Comment: Also see view> stackdriver executions instead

Comment: Thank you so much, @Cooper and @TheMaster!!! REALLY appreciate the guidance and direction!!!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you want to be doing one of these two types of sorts.  And I'd guess that you really want the first one.  The choice of ascending or descending is probably something different than what I have.

```
function sorttest1() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  rg.sort([{column:1,ascending:true},{column:2,ascending:false},{column:3,ascending:false}]);
}

function sorttest2() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  rg.sort({column:1,ascending:true}).sort({column:2,ascending:false}).sort({column:3,ascending:false});
}
```

Comment: WOW! @Cooper!  *Thank you!!!!*  I'll give this a whirl tonight.  I *so* appreciate all of the help and advice you've given!  Hope you have a wonderful day!!!!!!